# Syntax error in number using query expression in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I got **Syntax error in number using query expression?** error while I run below code

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE StateBudget " & _
            " Set S_ID='" & Me.cbState & "'" & _
            ", C_ID=" & Me.cbCategory & _
            ", Year='" & Me.cbYear & "'" & _
            ", 1=" & Me.Ctl1 & _
            ", 2=" & Me.Ctl2 & _
            ", 3=" & Me.Ctl3 & _
            " WHERE S_ID = """ & _
            DLookup("ID", "States", "State='" & _
            Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State") & "'") & """"
```

***S_ID and Year are Text fields, C_ID and the rest 1,2,3 are Number fields.***
If there anything I missed? I am a beginner in programming so...

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of number Me.* fields is null, so SQL will have syntax error. Use Nz function for such kind arguments. For debugging create SQL in string variable before executing and dump content of this variable to Immediate window using `Debug.Print`. You will see the problem easily.

```
Dim strSQL

strSQL = "UPDATE StateBudget " & _
            " Set S_ID='" & Me.cbState & "'" & _
            ", C_ID=" & Nz(Me.cbCategory, 0) & _
            ", Year='" & Me.cbYear & "'" & _
            ", 1=" & Nz(Me.Ctl1, 0) & _
            ", 2=" & Nz(Me.Ctl2, 0) & _
            ", 3=" & Nz(Me.Ctl3, 0) & _
            " WHERE S_ID = """ & _
            DLookup("ID", "States", "State='" & _
            Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State") & "'") & """"

Debug.Print strSQL
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```